# java number guessing game with joptionpane allways says my input is 0 and i win even if its wrong?

Tags: java

I have to create a program that asks for a number between 1 and 10.
A random number between 1 and 10 is generated and it should then output if I have guessed correctly
with my guessed number and the secret number displayed.
Also, it should output if I have guessed too high or too low with the secret number displayed.
I have to use `joptionpane` in the main class with the calculations and comparisons done in an instantiable class. also I have to use `else` and `if-statement`s.
I have written the code but it outputs 0 as the guessed number no matter what number I choose also it tells me that I have guessed correctly even if i have it wrong.
here are the two sets of code I have written.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessApp{

public static void main(String args[]){
    int guessNum, secretNum, correct, tooHigh, tooLow;

    Guess myGuess;

    myGuess = new Guess();

    guessNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a number between 1 and 10"));

    myGuess.setGN(guessNum);
    myGuess.compute();
    guessNum = myGuess.getGuessNum();
    secretNum = myGuess.getSecretNum();
    tooHigh = myGuess.getTooHigh();
    tooLow = myGuess.getTooLow();
    correct = myGuess.getCorrect();

    if (guessNum==correct){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations your number is"+guessNum+"and the secret number is"+secretNum+"you have won the game");
    }
    else if (tooHigh==guessNum){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I'm sorry you have guessed too high, your number is"+guessNum+"and the secret number is"+secretNum);
    }
    else if (tooLow==guessNum){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I'm sorry you guessed too low, your number is"+guessNum+"and the secret number is"+secretNum);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Guess{

   private int guessNum, correct, tooHigh, tooLow, secretNum;

   public Guess(){
       guessNum = 0;
   }

   public void setGN(int guessNum){
   this.guessNum = guessNum;
   }

   public void setSN(int secretNum){
       this.secretNum = secretNum;
   }

   public void setCT(int correct){
   this.correct = correct;
   }

   public void setTH(int tooHigh){
   this.tooHigh = tooHigh;
   }

   public void setTL(int tooLow){
   this.tooLow = tooLow;
   }

public void compute(){
    guessNum = guessNum;
    secretNum = (int)(Math.random()*((10 - 1) +1)+1);
    if ((secretNum<guessNum)){
        guessNum = tooHigh;
    }
    else if ((secretNum>guessNum)){
        guessNum = tooLow;
    }
    else if ((secretNum==guessNum)){
        guessNum = correct;
    }
}

    public int getGuessNum(){
    return guessNum;
    }
    public int getSecretNum(){
        return secretNum;
    }
    public int getTooHigh(){
        return tooHigh;
    }
    public int getTooLow(){
        return tooLow;
    }
    public int getCorrect(){
        return correct;
    }
}
```

I have just started a java class so I'm new to this.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the random number ?

Comment: Where do `tooHigh`, `tooLow` etc get set in the `Guess` class? Your app seems way to compilcated for what it is...

Answer (score 0):

ints are initialized to 0. In your compute method no matter what guessnum is going to be set to 0 because it will be one of those three things. Then the first if will always be true because everything at this point is set to 0. I would suggest rewriting it a bit and using too high too low and correct as bools instead of ints. That would allow you to find the answers more clearly.

```
public void compute(){
    guessNum = guessNum;
    secretNum = (int)(Math.random()*((10 - 1) +1)+1);
    if ((secretNum<guessNum)){
        tooHigh = true;
    }
    else if ((secretNum>guessNum)){
        tooLow = true;
    }
    else if ((secretNum==guessNum)){
        correct = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will require a little rewriting elsewhere as well. Not just the compute class

Answer (score 0):

Here is some hint.

1. You should first generate a random number between 1 and 10.
2. Populate the guess number enterd
3. Comparion the guess number enterd with random number. If they are equal then show congratulation information.

If they are not equal. Then compare guess number with highest number and lowest number. And I think the tooHigh and tooLow shuold be declared as boolean type.

4.Use the boolean flags populated in step#3, you can know whether the number is correct or too high or too low.

In your code, what the values for tooHigh, tooLow etc. They are always zeros.

Change some logic in method compute in Guess class. And have a try then.

An example is below:

**Guess class**

```
public class Guess {

private int secretNum = 0;

public Guess() {
    generateSecretNum();
}

/**
 * generate a secret number
 */
public void generateSecretNum() {
    secretNum = (int) (Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1) + 1);
}

public boolean isTooHigh(int guessNum) {
    return guessNum > secretNum;
}

public boolean isTooLow(int guessNum) {
    return guessNum < secretNum;
}

/**
 * @return the secretNum
 */
public int getSecretNum() {
    return secretNum;
}

/**
 * @param secretNum
 *            the secretNum to set
 */
public void setSecretNum(int secretNum) {
    this.secretNum = secretNum;
}

}
```

**GuessApp class**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessApp {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Store the value user entered
    int guessNum = 0;

    // When an instance of Guess is created. A secret number is generated as
    // well.
    Guess myGuess = new Guess();

    guessNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter a number between 1 and 10"));

    if (myGuess.isTooHigh(guessNum)) {
        // Too High
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "I'm sorry you have guessed too high, your number is"
                        + guessNum + "and the secret number is " 
                        + myGuess.getSecretNum());

    } else if (myGuess.isTooLow(guessNum)) {
        //Too Low
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "I'm sorry you guessed too low, your number is" + guessNum
                        + "and the secret number is "
                        + myGuess.getSecretNum());
    } else {
        //Equal to secret number
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Congratulations your number is" + guessNum
                        + "and the secret number is "
                        + myGuess.getSecretNum() + "you have won the game");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: i have tried everything but I cannot get it to work. it works fine when I have everything in just one main class. but when I try to use a instantiable class it returns zero. I can get it to work with the scanner class but not qwith joptionpane and that's what I have to use for this test. its something very simple but I just cant find it :(

Comment: I've provided a simple example in my anwser. This example is very simple. The user can guess a value only once, and it will let him know whether it is too low, too high or correct. I would like you to improve this code: such as, Give the user 3 chances to guess.

Comment: Thank you very much I had been at it all day yesterday. we are starting loops next week so I will change the code and put it back up when I have finished it. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting your fields (guessNum, correct, tooHigh, etc) in your Guess class so inside compute you are basically always setting guessNum to 0. Then you say getCorrect which returns 0 and you compare 0 to 0. You do set secretNum to the random value. So you will always get the case that guessNum and correct both come back 0 but secretNum is a random number.

Without setting int fields (variables that are "owned" by a class rather than in the scope of a method) yourself they are automatically initialized to 0. Primitive types in a method do not initialize automatically but the rules are different for fields. Arrays of primitive numbers also initialize all elements to 0 whether they are a field or in a method.

I would suggest simplifying your Guess class (if a class is necessary for some reason). Here is a much simplified version:

```
public class GuessMySecret {
    private int secret = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    // constructors can be omitted if they don't have to do anything

    public boolean isTooLow(int guess) {
        return guess < secret;
    }
    public boolean isTooHigh(int guess) {
        return guess > secret;
    }
}

// in main

int yourGuess = /* get your number */ ;

GuessMySecret mySecret = new GuessMySecret();

if (mySecret.isTooLow(yourGuess)) {
    // respond
} else if (mySecret.isTooHigh(yourGuess)) {
    // respond
} else {
    // presume to be correct
}
```

Though if you want to have multiple rounds using this model you have to either make a new object each time or have the class able to generate a new number.